# How to specify the networkCredential param using xml in Serilog.Sinks.Email

Tags: serilog

I'm trying to setup this sink Serilog.Sinks.Email using xml

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:Email.restrictedToMinimumLevel" value="Warning" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Email.from" value="email-from" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Email.to" value="email-to" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Email.mailServer" value="mail-server" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Email.outputTemplate" value="tmpl" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Email.networkCredential" value="???" />
```

since networkCredential implements ICredentialsByHost, is possible to specify it using xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation in the config for the email sink, and/or appsettings support at the moment.